# How to set a usable Windows UI Automation Name property on a .NET Maui FlyoutItem?

Tags: .net, maui

In my apps, the default Windows UI Automation Name properties of .NET Maui FlyoutItems is "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ShellFlyoutItemView", which makes them unusable to customers using screen readers. I can't set SemanticProperties.Description on them, as the app's going to crash if I do that. Does anyone know how to set the UI Automation Names on the items? I couldn't find mention of flyouts at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8174.

Thank you very much for your feedback and patience.